# What changes needed in .spec file to rename installing software?

Tags: rpm-spec, centos8, nano

I am trying to rebuild **nano** rpm package on CentOS 8 so after installing it I will be able to run **nano** using command *newnano*.
After some googling I came to the conclusion that I need to change .spec file and build package using command `rpmbuild -ba nano.spec`.
Here is what I've already tried:

1. Changing name in the beginning of .spec file, so it looked like that: 
   `Summary: A small text editor` 
    `Name: newnano` 
    `...`

    But when I tried to build package there was error: `Bad exit status from '/var/tmp/rpm-tmp.DSP7dc (%prep)` 
    As I understand after unzip tar archive its tried to `cd newnano-2.9.8` but there is no such directory.
2. Adding alias in %install section: 
   `%install` 
    `cd build` 
    `%make install` 
    `rm -f %{buildroot}%{_infodir}/dir` 
   `alias newnano="nano"`  
    `...` 
   Building and installation was successful but alias was not created.
3. Using %package. I insert after `%description` and before `%prep` in original .spec this: 
   `%package -n newnano` 
    `Summary: test` 
    `%description -n newnano` 
    `test` 
   Also I add `-n newnano` to `%files` section. Building and installation was successful but new command was not added.

So how I have to change .spec file to achieve my goal?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a very simpe way to do it via `rpmrebuild` and `.rpm` `nano` package.

1. `rpmrebuild -enp nano.rpm`
2. In `.spec` file (it will open after previous comand) you should do these:

   - replace `Name: nano` with `Name: newnano` *(optional, but recommended)*
   - add `mv /usr/bin/nano /usr/bin/newnano` before the first `exit 0` line. This section you can find before `%changelog`
3. Look carefully and remember the path of rebuilded `.rpm` that you will see after you close `vim`
4. Install rebuilded `.rpm` via `rpm -i` command
5. *(Optional: maybe you will need to reboot)*

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to do a few things:

1. Get the current specfile (looks like you did that)
2. Change the name of the RPM (looks good)
3. Change the name of the GNU package (hint: look in [configure.ac](https://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/nano.git/tree/configure.ac))
4. Add another patch to the RPM that modifies the final executables (hint: look in [src/Makefile.am](https://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/nano.git/tree/src/Makefile.am) - you want to rename `nano` and remove the `rnano` symlink)
5. Rebuild

Instead of messing with `src/Makefile.am`, you can *probably* rename things in the `%install` stanza of the specfile, but I don't know enough about `nano` to tell you if it will be still identifying itself properly, etc.

Have fun!